# Read access violation of std::shared_ptr

Tags: visual-studio, c++14, sfml, smart-pointers

I'm working on a personal project using SFML and C++. The project has an interface and some buttons. So... I have a `SortingAlgorithms` class, which will be a base class and a subclass `BubbleSort`

```
class SortingAlgorithms 
{
protected:
    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> sequence;
    sf::RenderWindow& window;
    int minimum, maximum;
    int elements;

public:
    SortingAlgorithms();

    // Class constructor which initializes a sequence
    SortingAlgorithms(int min, int max, int els, sf::RenderWindow& win);

    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> GetSequence() const;

    // A pure virtual function for overriding 
    virtual void Sort(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init) = 0;

    // A method for printing the sequence
    void Print(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init);
};

class BubbleSort : public SortingAlgorithms
{
public:
    BubbleSort(int min, int max, int els, sf::RenderWindow& win);
    void Sort(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init);
};
```

The main problem is in the `Sort` method which has some button events too. What I am trying to do in this method is simply printing a sequence or a sorted sequence using an `std::shared_ptr(generatedAlg)` which will be initialized on this branch `if (selectedAlg == "Bubble Sort")`; everything works fine but if it gets to this point `if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == "Sort")` I get

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::shared_ptr<SortingAlgorithms>::operator-><SortingAlgorithms,0>(...) returned nullptr.
```

Similarly happens when I try to allocate it manually too :

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'generatedAlg' is being used without being initialized.
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
void Interface::ConfigBar(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init)
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        std::shared_ptr<SortingAlgorithms> generatedAlg;
        
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            for (std::vector<Button>::iterator it = configButtons.begin(); it != configButtons.end(); it = std::next(it))
            {
                switch (event.type)
                {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true)
                    {
                        (*it).SetTextColor(sf::Color::White);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (*it).SetTextColor(sf::Color::Black);
                    }
                    break;
                case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (std::distance(configButtons.begin(), it) != 5 && std::distance(configButtons.begin(), it) != 6 && std::distance(configButtons.begin(), it) != 9))
                    {
                        (*it).SetShapeColor(sf::Color(0, 109, 119));
                    }
                    break;
                case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (std::distance(configButtons.begin(), it) != 5 && std::distance(configButtons.begin(), it) != 6 && std::distance(configButtons.begin(), it) != 9))
                    {
                        (*it).SetTextColor(sf::Color::Black);
                        (*it).SetShapeColor(sf::Color(42, 157, 143));
                    }
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == ">")
                    {
                        inputMin += 10;
                        configButtons.at(5).SetButton(std::to_string(inputMin));
                    }
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == "<")
                    {
                        inputMax += 10;
                        configButtons.at(6).SetButton(std::to_string(inputMax));
                    }
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == "+")
                    {
                        inputEls += 1;
                        configButtons.at(9).SetButton(std::to_string(inputEls));
                    }
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == "-")
                    {
                        inputEls -= 1;
                        if (inputEls < 0)
                        {
                            inputEls = 0;
                            std::cerr << "Cannot be less than 0" << std::endl;
                        }
                        configButtons.at(9).SetButton(std::to_string(inputEls));
                    }
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == "Reset")
                    {
                        inputMin = 0;
                        inputMax = 0;
                        inputEls = 0;
                        configButtons.at(5).SetButton(std::to_string(inputMin));
                        configButtons.at(6).SetButton(std::to_string(inputMax));
                        configButtons.at(9).SetButton(std::to_string(inputEls));
                    }
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == "Generate")
                    {
                        if (inputMin == 0 || inputMax == 0 || inputEls == 0)
                        {
                            std::cout << "Cannot generate a sequence by default configuration" << std::endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (selectedAlg == "Bubble Sort")
                        {
                            generatedAlg = std::make_shared<BubbleSort>(inputMin, inputMax, inputEls, window);
                            generatedAlg->Print(init);
                        
                        }
                        std::cout << "Sequence generated" << std::endl;
                    }
                    if ((*it).DetectButton(window) == true && (*it).GetButton() == "Sort")
                    {
                        //generatedAlg = std::make_shared<BubbleSort>(inputMin, inputMax, inputEls, window);
                        generatedAlg->Sort(init);
                        
                        std::cout << "The sequence is now sorted" << std::endl;
                    }
                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                    {
                        if (algorithmType == "Sorting Algorithms")
                            SortingAlgMenu(init);
                        PathAlgMenu(init);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color(sf::Color::White));
        for (std::vector<Button>::iterator it = configButtons.begin(); it != configButtons.end(); it = std::next(it))
        {
            (*it).Draw(window);
        }
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's saying that something is using `generatedAlg` when it's still empty. Time to use a debugger to figure out why this happens.

Comment: There's too much unimportant code in your example and some missing parts like contents of `DetectButton` and `GetButton` functions. Try to boil it down to a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: `generatedAlg` is a local variable in the loop. It's created anew at each iteration of the loop, and discarded at the end. You seem to expect it to carry its value between "Generate" button click and "Sort" button click, but it won't. At least, move it out of the loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah... I've tried that and I still got the same issue...

Comment: Show the code you are running now.

Comment: I found the issue I think

Comment: I'm recalling this method from Print or Sort whenever I press esc key. So... I guess the solution would be to declare the shared ptr inside the Interface class.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I've declared the shared ptr inside Interface. Now I'm unable to call methods from BubbleSort subclass... Do you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"?  What's stopping you? What happens when you try?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I get this error : 'E0044 expression must have pointer type'

Comment: What expression does the error refer to? I can't help with code I can't see.